# Classic asp persist custom classes in session

Tags: session, asp-classic, object, persistence

Is it possible to persist a class in session that I define in VBScript in classic asp:

```
<script runat=server language=vbscript> 

Class clsCourse 
Private Sub Class_Initialize 
' Statements go here.
End Sub
End Class

dim oCourse
set oCourse=new clsCourse
</script>
```

How would I persist oCourse in session and recover it from session?

I *know* session is bad, but this is a high volume application and I'm concerned about hitting the database multiple times in a page call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Take a look at these answers for a more thorough explanation [Classic ASP Store objects in the session object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196525/classic-asp-store-objects-in-the-session-object)

Unfortunately you can't store classes in session. This page gives a good explanation:

https://web.archive.org/web/20061026090950/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=195

One solution could be to make the class a wrapper for an array and just store that array in session.