# How do I consume Classes i have stored in Application?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have defined a class like this:

```
Class Foo
    Public SomePublicProperty

    Public Function init(p_somePublicProperty)
        set init = Me

        SomePublicProperty= p_somePublicProperty
    End Function
End Class
```

And then consumed that in my global.asa `Application_OnStart` lke this:

```
Dim fooInstance 

Set fooInstance = New Foo.init("Some data")

fooArray = Array(fooInstance)

Application("fooArray") = fooArray
```

Which works fine but when i get the value back out of the application store on another page i can't get at the property...

```
fooArray = Application("fooArray")

fooArray(0).SomePublicProperty 'This line returns an error - Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I have tried putting the class definition into the second page, but it doesn't help.

What have I missed?

---

I have just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196525/classic-asp-store-objects-in-the-session-object) question. Am I right in assuming the same rule re serialization applies equally to the Application object? and so i shouldn't try and do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do this, here is a the best explanation I could find as to why;

> <sup>From [Can I store VBScript class objects in a Session variable?](https://web.archive.org/web/20061026090950/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=195)</sup>
> *This is because VBS classes are **NOT** true classes. They are really just in-memory collections of info, and there is no way to guarantee (for example) that an instance that is stored in one page will even come close to matching the class definition in another page.*

This is not the same as using `Server.CreateObject()` COM objects which can be stored and retrieved from both the `Application` and `Session` objects.

You have a couple of options;

- Serialise the object yourself, in a structured string then use this to de-serialise the object when needed.
- Create a COM wrapper for your VBScript class and stop using `Class` statement altogether. As COM objects can be stored in `Application` and `Session` objects this should work as long as the COM class is single threaded.
- Convert your class into an `Array` and use this instead.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Application Object (IIS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525360(v=vs.90).aspx)
- [Setting the Scope of COM Objects in ASP Pages - Giving an Object Application Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525036(v=vs.90).aspx#h2_37783263)

Comment: `fooArray` is an array, so no `Set`.

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner Have modified the answer.